# Blender Crashes [Possibly Nvidia Driver Problem]

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

At first my problem started when using programs such as Substance Painter and Substance Designer - they stopped launching, completely. So I contacted Allegorithmic support, and in the end we deleted Iray folders from SP and SD software, and then those programs started working, although we came to conclusion that there is a problem between Iray and Nvidia Cuda driver. 
Now I've detected problems with blender - whenever I try to add a new material in cycles, it crashes instantly, or whenever I try to render my scene in cycles, it crashes instantly. Some very big scenes that I have stopped opening at all, they instantly crush. Also I can't open "system" menu in the preferences, it crashes instantly.  I have tried to reinstall my Nvidia driver many times, several times I have cleaned old version of it completely, it didn't help. What is interesting is that Videogames run fine so far, but 3D redactor programs don't. I really don't know what to do. Perhaps there is a problem with graphics card? That would be very sad ;(
I have run a test of my Intel Processor from official intel website, it passed it, so hopefully Processor is alright. I have also reinstalled my blender, didn't help. I have also performed a clean installation of Nvidia drivers using DDU program, didn't help. 
Anyone have any idea what to do?

Full application error log from substance painter:

Name of failed Application: Substance Painter.exe, version: 2018.2.1.0, time marker: 0x5b645cf0

Name of crushed module: nvcuda.dll, version: 23.21.13.8871, time marker: 0x5a3449b2

Exception code: 0xc0000005

Error offset: 0x0000000000317665

ID of failed process: 0x3168

Launch time of crushed application: 0x01d0d1dbda2c7290

Path to crushed application: D:\Steam\steamapps\common\Substance Painter 2018\Substance Painter.exe

Path to crushed module: C:\WINDOWS\system32\nvcuda.dll

Report ID: 2f914d9c-a893-40e4-be83-8af0b8d69596

Link to the allegorithmic support forum topic I made: https://forum.allegorithmic.com/index.php/topic,25095.0.html

Comment: What GPU do you have?

Comment: Geforce 1060 gtx

Comment: I have them same issue. Just update your graphics card driver.

Comment: I did it numerous times, didn't help.